# How to sort a distance matrix in mathematica

Tags: plotting, matrix, sorting

I have the following code which results in the heatmap shown:

```
indexnames2 = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"};
tblname = "Test Plot"
distmat = {{1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.022, 0.015, 0, 0, 0, 0.0074}, {0, 
    1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.45, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {0.022, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0.63, 0, 0, 0, 0.20}, {0.015, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.63, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0.12}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1.0, 0.20, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.20, 1.0, 0, 0}, {0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0}, {0.0075, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.20, 0.12, 0, 0, 0, 1.0}};
ticks = Transpose[{Range[Length[indexnames2]], indexnames2}];
color[z_] := 
 Which[z == 0, Blue, 0 < z < 1, 
  ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[z, {0, 1}]]]

Legended[MatrixPlot[distmat, ColorFunction -> color, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, RotateLabel -> True, 
  ImageSize -> {500, 500}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style[tblname, FontSize -> 18], 
  FrameTicks -> {ticks, None, None, 
    MapAt[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &, ticks, {All, 2}]}], 
 BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}]]
```

[image]

I would like for the entries to be sorted so the most similar entities are shown in the top right and the least similar are shown in the bottom right.  Is there a Mathematica function for this that would make the plot look more like the one shown below (I know this one is also not sorted but it does show some clustering like I want to achieve.)?

[image]

Comment: Use `FindClusters` or `FindGraphCommunities`.

Comment: One thing to try is "minimum bandwidth" -- see the answer here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32007/1783

Comment: I'm not sure if `FindClusters` can work with a pre-computed distance matrix, but perhaps you have the source data too. Sorry, no time for a full answer, but I hope these are useful references.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`ResourceFunction["SymmetricSort"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SymmetricSort/).

I am defining "most similar" to be number of near-by entities and small distance to those entities.  Using `distmat` as in OP.

```
MatrixPlot[distmat, FrameTicks -> Range@12]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Can [`Count`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Count.html) the number of zero entries (small if many near-bys) and [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) the distances (small if close).

```
close = Through[{Count[0], Total}@#] & /@ distmat;
Short[close, .5]
```

> ```
> {{8,1.0444},{11,1.},<<9>>,{8,1.3275}}
> ```

Take the [`Ordering`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html) of the `close` metrics. Numerical ordering will do since we want smallest values in both metrics.

```
sortIndex = Ordering[close]
```

> ```
> {1, 12, 8, 7, 9, 10, 5, 11, 2, 3, 4, 6}
> ```

`sortIndex` give the order of the items (indexed 1 to 12) in the sorted matrix. For example, the 12th item should placed in the 2nd position of the new matrix.

[`ResourceFunction["SymmetricSort"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SymmetricSort/) `distmat` with `sortIndex`.

```
ssdistmat = ResourceFunction["SymmetricSort"][distmat, sortIndex];
MatrixPlot[ssdistmat
 , FrameTicks -> 
  ConstantArray[{MapIndexed[Flatten@Reverse@{##} &, sortIndex], None}, 2]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The distance matrix is sorted by similarity.

Hope this helps.